# mysql query not returning result if data is not in table

Tags: php, select, mysqli

Here is the query that almost works:

```
$query  = '';
$query .= ' SELECT highway_code.charge_id, 
        highway_code.act_abbr, 
        highway_code.short_form_wording, 
        highway_code.section, 
        highway_code.set_fine,  
        highway_code_arrest_jail_tow.demerits
        ';
$query .= ' FROM highway_code, highway_code_arrest_jail_tow ';
$query .= ' WHERE highway_code.charge_id = ? ';
$query .= ' AND highway_code.section = highway_code_arrest_jail_tow.section ';
$query .= ' AND highway_code.act_abbr = highway_code_arrest_jail_tow.act_abbr ';
```

The problem is that not all highway code charges have demerits, thus any charges without demerits are not returned, even though all the other fields apply.  I would like to have all charges returned regardless if there is a value in `highway_code_arrest_jail_tow`.

Comment: You need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the implicit `INNER JOIN` you have here (via comma-separated table names)  Review http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I think that's the best explanation I've seen on the topic.  However, as a novice with limited experience in creating SQL statements, I'm not sure how i'd write it out...  I'm starting to do the research now, but if the solution is simple, would you mind posting?  Tks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause as you have it, with an equality condition between the related columns implies an `INNER JOIN`.  To enforce all records being returned from the primary table regardless of the presence of related records in the related table, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

I'll replace your implicit inner join with an explicit `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  highway_code.charge_id, 
  highway_code.act_abbr, 
  highway_code.short_form_wording, 
  highway_code.section, 
  highway_code.set_fine,  
  highway_code_arrest_jail_tow.demerits
FROM
  highway_code
  LEFT JOIN highway_code_arrest_jail_tow
     /* Two relating conditions belong in the ON clause */
     ON highway_code.section = highway_code_arrest_jail_tow.section
     AND highway_code.act_abbr = highway_code_arrest_jail_tow.act_abbr
WHERE
  /* and the filtering condition remains in the WHERE */
  highway_code.charge_id = ?
```

Comment: You sir, are amazing.  I was so close, it was the WHERE at the end I was juggling with.  Thank you so much Michael.